# How to turn off mouse deceleration/acceleration?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, mouse

When I play Minecraft Windows Edition, the screen does not move at the exact speed as the mouse. Instead, it has some acceleration/deceleration, which makes it very annoying compared to Java edition.
I assume there is a way to turn this off.  I tried turning on and off **Enhance Pointer Precision**, but that didn't do anything.
Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

The setting you are looking for is **Sensitivity**, under **Keyboard & Mouse** settings. A higher sensitivity will increase the effect moving the mouse will have in-game.

Comment: Mouse sensitivity and Mouse acceleration is different thing.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for.  The problem i have is that the screen does not follow the mouse at the same constant speed as the mouse pointer itself is moving.